# Parse.com/Nodejs http-request special characters removed

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, parse-platform, amazon-mws

I'm accessing amazons MWS-Api via parse.com (which is build upon nodejs) and have issues with their flatfile-reports (the getreport endpoint). All special characters (ä, ö, ü) are simply removed. According to the MWS-Support, they are using the CP1252-Encoding. Here's the request code.

```
// Parse.Cloud.httpRequest is parses version of the nodejs http-module
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: "https://mws.amazonservices.de/?",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        "Host": "mws.amazonservices.de",
        "x-amazon-user-agent": "MyUserAgent(Language=Javascript)",
        "Accept-Charset": "CP1252"
    },
    body: queryString
    success: function(resp){
            response.success(resp)
        }
    },
    error: function(err){
        response.error(err)
    }
```

The response-headers I'm receiving look as follows:

```
  {
  "Connection": "close",
  "Content-Length": "395828",
  "Content-MD5": "Xw8KYGqESc7u4TTzgcbT/g==",
  "Content-Type": "text",
  "Date": "Thu, 13 Aug 2015 10:21:00 GMT",
  "Server": "AmazonMWS",
  "Vary": "Accept-Encoding,User-Agent",
  "x-amz-request-id": "xxxxx",
  "x-mws-quota-max": "60.0",
  "x-mws-quota-remaining": "58.0",
  "x-mws-quota-resetsOn": "2015-08-13T10:38:00.000Z",
  "x-mws-request-id": "xxxxx",
  "x-mws-response-context": "C0ywPcTe0K9qESsoz4OzZX9oRJMDuYR9vvk5MfN3KKOGEnyWgSZlOQDixINemnwLVZl0DjXEdrY=",
  "x-mws-timestamp": "2015-08-13T10:21:01.186Z"
}
```

To clarify, the special characters are not being garbled (no "�" or anything like it). "Für" is simply received as "Fr".Oddly, I have the same issue with amazons scratchpad (https://mws.amazonservices.de/scratchpad/index.html), which should, according to the MWS-Support, show the special characters properly.
Thanks for any help in advance.

edit1: Also, a coworker of mine has a very similar issue with parse, in a completely unrelated project (different data-source n everything). After a bit of experimenting in python, I'm fairly certain his datafeed is encoded in latin1, not utf8, which seems to cause the issue. Any way of enforcing latin1 or CP1252 encoding in parse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Amazon support confirmed that it was a bug on their end and, from what I can tell, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are already requesting parse.com to send you the data in utf-8.

Pay attention to these lines:

```
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    "Accept-Charset": "utf-8"
```

Changing these values to latin1 might work, if you can draw parallels with your collegue.

However, [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-save-special-characters-with-rest-api) question on the parse.com forums may shed some light onto your issue. It could be a client(your)-side issue. Have you tried changing your side's encoding?

Comment: You misunderstood. The request sent form the code in my question goes to amazon. I'm not ever requesting anything from parse. The response from amazon will be processed in parse and saved in the database. There is no "client-side", or rather, the parse cloud code is the client-side.
The response header from amazon doesn't specify any encoding, however the MWS support reported that all reports are encoded in CP1252. The latin1 issue is just related insofar that in both cases we need a way to specify the encoding of the received response in parse.